# Regex for matching word but not if it starts or ends with hyphen or colon

Tags: regex, ruby

I've been having trouble figuring out the correct regex (in Ruby) for matching a word in a string, but not if the word starts or ends with a `-` or `:`.

I currently have:

```
/\bmatch this\b/i
```

The regex should match (`match this`) in:

```
 please match this!
 do not match this.
```

but not match:

```
do not :match this
do not -match this
do not match this:
do not match this-
```

I've tried:

```
/\b[^:-]match this[^:-]\b/i
```

I'd appreciate any help! I'm using the regex in Ruby, if it makes a difference.

Comment: I think you mean matching a string in a string, not a word in a string, in view of your example. It's good to see you figured out how to do that. As an exercise think how you would match a string that could start or end with a minus or colon, but could not both begin with a minus or colon and end with a minus or colon.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, using a negated lookbehind, and a negative lookahead

```
/(?<![:-])\bmatch this\b(?![:-])/i
```